# Unable to find Dynamic Xpath

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My xpath is :

> //*[@id='form_MenuBar:j_id24']/span

and the value # 24 changes.

> //*[@id='form_MenuBar:j_id48']/span

I tried but doesn't works.

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'form_MenuBar:j_id$')]/span"));

Source XML:

```
<li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-menuitem-active" role="menuitem">
  <a id="form_MenuBar:j_id24" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" href="/Demand/j_spring_security_logout">
    <span class="ui-menuitem-text">Log off</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you post the html for the element you are looking for? Also, have you tried by just using 'form_MenuBar:j_id'? Certain symbols cause problems when using xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'form_MenuBar:j_id')]/span"));
```

If you are using contains in xpath no need to use `'$'`.

Comment: It didn't work. My code snippet is <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-menuitem-active" role="menuitem">
<a id="form_MenuBar:j_id24" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" href="/Demand/j_spring_security_logout">
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">Log off</span>
</a>
</li>

Comment: @Riy1234, his solution works for me. Is it in an iFrame? What is the exact XPath you are using? What browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: No It's not in frame. The Xpath is log_out=//*[@id='form_MenuBar:j_id24']/span , Firefox 15 and selenium java version=2.28

Comment: You can do one thing. Just record your clicks in Selenium IDE and check whether its setting Some frame Before click. I think, As you want to click on LogOut , it may be coming in the Default Frame so try to Use driver.switchTo().defaultContent() before your click on Log Out.

Comment: I tried with List<WebElement> list= top.findElements(By.Tagname("iframe")); No iframe exists

Comment: @Riy1234, put that XPath into the Selenium IDE...does it find anything?

Comment: It gives the direct ID as 24 next time when changes it fails. I also found that in my page there are 2 to 3 elements with id //a[contains(@id,'form_MenuBar:j_id24')]/span another //a[contains(@id,'form_MenuBar:j_id53')]/span, Even if i try reg exp it will fail

Comment: @Riy1234, in which case the XPath @Arun gave you, won't work. See if something as simple as `//span[text()='Log off']` gets you the element, it may not be reliable but should at least get the element.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using java so I'll try to answer it based on that.  I'm not a java developer so I apologize if it's not syntactically correct.

If all that is changing is the number within the ID, and you know the ID, you could do:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(String.format("form_MenuBar:j_id%d", the_id));
```

Also, I'm not sure about your application that you are testing, but if there are multiple elements that have an id beginning with "form_MenuBar:j_id", then findElement will only find the first one, which might not be the link you are attempting to find.

you could use findElements which will return a list of all elements that match that and then iterate through those until you find the one you really want.